# How to sort using dynamoose

Tags: node.js, sorting, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to sort items from DynamoDB using dynamoose in NodeJS

descending() and ascending() are the two functions provided in dynamoose npm for sorting, but i didn't get that work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use descending and ascending with ONLY Query (its not working with scan). Heres working example that I have used for querying my data.

```
Devices.query('device_id').eq('123').where('created_at').gt(lastMonth).ascending().exec();
```

https://dynamoosejs.com/api#queryascending

And same for descending:

```
Devices.query('device_id').eq('123').where('created_at').gt(lastMonth). descending().exec();
```

https://dynamoosejs.com/api#querydescending

Comment: Hi there, any idea how to achieve the same for all records on the table ? something like `Devices.query('created_at').ascending().exec();`

Comment: @marman, what I've seen done is using a "sort" key that is set to the same value for all records of a table. Then you can do something like `Devices.query('sort').eq('DEFAULT').where('created_at').ascending().exec();`

Answer (score 0):

```
const {SortOrder} = require("dynamoose/dist/General");

Cat.query("name").eq("Will").sort(SortOrder.descending);
```

https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Query/#querysortorder